# Android App with Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Android Studio and I would like to connect my App to the internet. I want to save the highscores in Google (high replication) Datastore.

In Eclipse with the Google-plugin it seem'd to be very easy(just create a new web application and connect it). But how does it work in Android Studio? I tryed to do something with Endpoints and stuff but nothing really worked.

Answer (score 8):

You can do the same thing also with the Android Studio.

1) There is a nice and simple tutorial on GitHub by Google on how to build a GAE endpoints application (Step-by-step guide): 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

2) For connecting with a database you have to add the objectivity dependency:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'
```

You could also use JPA or another ORM framework. Objectifity is specifically designed for the GAE (https://github.com/objectify/objectify):

> Objectify is a Java data access API specifically designed for the Google App Engine datastore. It occupies a "middle ground"; easier to use and more transparent than JDO or JPA, but significantly more convenient than the Low-Level API. Objectify is designed to make novices immediately productive yet also expose the full power of the GAE datastore.

3) I recomend that you check out on how to use objectivity: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify

4) Create your Entities:

```
//com.example.backend.entities
@Entity
public  class Customer  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=   GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long    id;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;

//getters and setters
//...

}
```

5) Generate the endpoints:
The Endpoints provide the API for the Android client.

- Right click on the entity you want to expose to the client (e.g. Customer).
- Select **Generate Cloud Endpoint from Java class**. This generates a basic API
  description and implementation for the selected entity. It already creates the
  methods get / insert / list / patch/ remove / update. This generates also the libraries for the client. **Please pay attention if you use this generated methods in production!**

6) Create an AsyncTask in your Android application (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-andthreads.html#AsyncTask):

> AsyncTask allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user interface. It performs the blocking
>   operations in a worker thread and then publishes the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to
>   handle threads and/or handlers yourself.
>   To use it, you must subclass AsyncTask and implement the doInBackground() callback method, which
>   runs in a pool of background threads. To update your UI, you should implement onPostExecute(), which
>   delivers the result from doInBackground() and runs in the UI thread, so you can safely update your UI.
>   You can then run the task by calling execute() from the UI thread.

On the GitHub tutorial you find the basic implementation how to create an AsyncTask and how to connect the Android client to the backend:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

7) Deploy your application to the backend:

- Create a new project under https://console.developers.google.com/
- **Project name**: Name of the project
- **Project id**: Name used to access the backend: The root URL to your project is https://*projectId*.appspot.com/.

After your project is created you have to open Android Studio and go to **Build/Deploy Module to App Engine**

- **Module**: your backend module
- **Deploy to**: select your created project - You have to login with your Google account. All your projects are shown and you can select the project you want to deploy to.
- **Version**: version number - You can deploy different versions of your application. As default the Version 1 is loaded if you access your project. You can change the
  version by adding the version number infront of the project id (e.g. https://2.*projectId*.appspot.com/ - this will load the version 2).
- Click on **deploy**. Now you have to change the root URL from
  http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/ to your project URL.

Under https://console.google.com/ you can select your project. There is some useful
information about your project:
- Under Monitoring/Logs you find a list with log entries that have been triggered.
- Under Storage/Cloud Datastore/Query you can see the data inside of your
database

I hope this guides you on solving your problem. There are a lot more information available on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs. I recommend you to read on this site to get a better overview over GAE.

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick answer.
what i would do now is, 1) adding a Endpoints Module to my Project. 
2) Creating my Entity classes and register them (i.e. highscore)
3) Generate the endpoints 
4) "Create an AsyncTask in your Android application"? What is that ? and do i need it when i just want to store my data?
5)Deploy to App Engine.

Is this alright or do you have any other tips ?

Comment: You need an AsyncTask to send the data over the internet to the backend. My answer should provide you the information on how to tackle your problem. If you have problems during the implementation you can ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Now that with Google Cloud Functions you have the options to send your requests from your mobile app to Cloud Function and from the Cloud function you can query the data from your Datastore. Here is the Library to integrate Datastore with Cloud functions https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java#google-cloud-datastore-ga